# Proximity prompt toggle inventory

Tags: lua, roblox

How do I make it so when the player presses the letter on assigned on the proximity prompt it removes everything from the player inventory. But when pressed again it gives it back to them.

This is what I have.

```lua
local proximityPrompt = script.Parent
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

if proximityPrompt.Triggered == true then
    ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("Tool") Destroy()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use "ServerStorage" instead of "ReplicatedStorage" because in "ReplicatedStorage" cheaters can add or remove items from it, but in "ServerStorage" they cannot because in "ServerStorage" items are stored on the server. In "ReplicatedStorage" items are also stored on server, but the player has access to them.

Here is the script.

```
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local backpacks = Instance.new("Folder", ServerStorage)
backpacks.Name = "backpacks"

ProximityPromptLocation.Triggered:Connect(function(plr)
    if #plr.Backpack:GetChildren() == 0 then
        for i, tool in pairs(backpacks[plr.UserId]:GetChildren()) do
            tool.Parent = plr.Backpack
        end
    else
        for i, tool in pairs(plr.Backpack:GetChildren()) do
            tool.Parent = backpacks[plr.UserId]
        end
    end
end)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local plrBackpack = Instance.new("Folder", backpacks)
    plrBackpack.Name = plr.UserId
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
    backpacks[plr.UserId]:Destroy()
end)
```

Change "ProximityPromptLocation" to your proximity prompt location

This script needed to be global and located in the "ServerScriptStorage" or in the "Workspace".

Again better to put this script to "ServerScriptStorage" because of the same reason as using "ServerStorage" instead of "ReplicatedStorage"

This code will create a "backpacks" folder in "ServerStorage". When a player joins a game, it will create a player backpack folder named player's user id in the "backpacks" folder. When the player leaves the game, the created folder will be deleted. When the player triggers the proximity prompt, it checks if the player's inventory has zero items, if true, each item will be moved to the player backpack folder with name of player’s user id, if false, each item will be moved to the player's inventory.